# Regular Expression to remove non alpha-numeric characters from start/end of <td>

Tags: c#, regex

I am using .NET/C# and I would like to create the following regular expression. I would like to remove non-alpha numeric characters from start/end of string inside .  It would not affect the intermediate data.(Data inside the alpha numeric area). Only the data before and after the alpha-numeric characters as follows:

For example:

```
Input:
<td>;[Bob Smith:</td><h1>.#</h1>
<td>    Mary L. Jane    ?    </td>
<td>- + Mike T+ Rodgers + </td>
<td>@#1236^&</td>
<td>  -54-321A-</td>

Output:
<td>Bob Smith</td><h1>.#</h1>
<td>Mary L. Jane</td>
<td>Mike T+ Rodgers</td>
<td>1236</td>
<td>54-321A</td>
```

Thanks Before Hand

Comment: Best take a look at something like `HTMLAgilityPack` http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ which has a lot of functions which will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@"(?<=<td>)[^\da-zA-Z<]+|[^\da-zA-Z>]+(?=</td>)"` as a pattern. (used positive lookaround assertions)

For example:

```
string str = @"<td>;[Bob Smith:</td><h1>.#</h1>
<td>    Mary L. Jane    ?    </td>
<td>- + Mike T+ Rodgers + </td>
<td>@#1236^&</td>
<td>  -54-321A-</td>";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(
    str,
    @"(?<=<td>)[^\da-zA-Z<]+|[^\da-zA-Z>]+(?=</td>)",
    "");
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
```

Comment: falsetru, nice work but check this input please:  "<td></td>"

Comment: @user3062349, Use `@"(?<=<td>)[^\da-zA-Z<]+|[^\da-zA-Z>]+(?=</td>)"`.

Comment: falsetru, thank you for your help. great work.  Not sure if "update 1" above can be done.  It seems I am removing too much if its done on all the td's.

Comment: @user3062349, Please post another question.

Comment: falsetru, I have done as requested and removed the comments from this question.  Here is the new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803076/regular-expression-to-remove-non-alpha-numeric-characters-from-start-end-of-firs

Comment: I have also marked your answer as the answer for this one.  Thank you!